(gnome-control-center:52006): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:41:51.236: cannot open display: :1
I cannot open my gnome-control-center and gedit. The output in my terminal is:
(gnome-control-center:52006): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:41:51.236: cannot open display: :1

And I also tried
sudo gnome-control-center

The output is:
(gnome-control-center:51985): info-cc-panel-WARNING **: 16:41:41.048: Unable to retrieve org.gnome.SessionManager.Renderer property

Segmentation fault

How do I solve this problem?
